# calculate running total using multiple filters

Tags: dax

I am trying to output a value on a power BI report, equal to the running total for the current fiscal year.

The underlying table contains multiple FY values, and is organized such that each charge has a calculated field containing the fiscal year it was applied to, but there are also projected monthly charges in the table which are in the future.

For example, if I choose FY 2022, I want to return a sum of all charges for FY 2022 which have occurred prior to today.

The following snippet returns all FY charges, including future ones labelled FY 2022

`Cum FY Invoice Total = CALCULATE('Invoice Amounts'[Invoice Total],FILTER(ALL('Calendar'),'Calendar'[Fiscal Year]=2022))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have posted wrong cumulative sum formula because correct formula should include `&& 'Calendar'[Date] < MAX('Calendar'[Date])` condition.

Also do not forget that you can write more complex conditions inside FILTER() function using && (AND) or || (OR).

I added `&& 'Calendar'[Date] < NOW()` to your measure and filtered out future charges.

```
Cum FY Invoice Total = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Invoice Amounts'[Invoice Total]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Calendar'),
        'Calendar'[Fiscal Year] = 2022
            && 'Calendar'[Date] < MAX('Calendar'[Date])
            && 'Calendar'[Date] < NOW()
    )
)
```

If you do not want to see future charges at all then you should write one more measure:

```
Hide Future Charges = 
INT(
    SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Date]) < NOW()
)
```

and add it to your visual on Filters panel choosing 1 as filter value:
[Future charges hiding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uralu.jpg)